# How can I print from an object?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am having a problem getting my program to print an array. I have created a class with code and I want to be able to use the class to print the array. I have submitted my code below. hopefully Y'all can help me out thanks.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO
Imports FinalLIB

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fsrFile As StreamReader = New StreamReader("Cars.csv")
    Dim line, splitLine(1) As String
    Dim bestCars(14) As Cars
    Dim counter As Integer

    Do Until fsrFile.EndOfStream
        line = fsrFile.ReadLine
        splitLine = Split(line, ",")
        bestCars(counter) = New Cars(splitLine(0), (splitLine(1)), (splitLine(2)), (splitLine(3)))
        counter += 1
    Loop
    Dim strCarMake, strCarModel, intyear, strColorc As Cars
    Console.WriteLine(bestCars(3))
End Sub
```

This is the code from my library created.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Cars

Private strCarMake As String
Private strCarModel As String
Private intYear As String
Private strColor As String

Public Sub New(ByVal bvstrCarMake As String, ByVal bvstrCarModel As String, ByVal bvintYear As String, ByVal bvstrColor As String)
    prpCarMake = bvstrCarMake
    prpYear = CInt(bvintYear)
    prpCarModel = bvstrCarModel
    prpColor = bvstrColor
End Sub

Public Property prpCarMake() As String
    Get
        Return strCarMake
    End Get
    Set(bvstrCarMake As String)
        strCarMake = bvstrCarMake
    End Set
End Property

Public Property prpCarModel() As String
    Get
        Return strCarModel
    End Get
    Set(bvstrCarModel As String)
        strCarModel = bvstrCarModel
    End Set
End Property

Public Property prpYear() As Integer
    Get
        Return CInt(intYear)
    End Get
    Set(bvintYear As Integer)
        intYear = CType(bvintYear, String)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property prpColor() As String
    Get
        Return strColor
    End Get
    Set(bvstrColor As String)
        strColor = bvstrColor
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property prpIsOld() As Boolean
    Get
        If prpYear > 2010 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Get
End Property

'Public ReadOnly Property prpSSN() As String
'Get
'Return strSSN
'End Get
'End Property

Public Function ReturnFullInfo() As String
    Return "Make: " & prpCarMake & " Model: " & prpCarModel & "Year: " & prpYear & "Color: " & prpColor
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: VB.NET is *not* the same as VBA. Please pay attention when tagging your questions. If you tag incorrectly you won't get the attention of the people who could help you! Also, please format your code blocks correctly: you need at least four spaces at the beginning of each line to keep the code in a block. Or select it and use the code tool on the toolbar.

Comment: Going forward you might want to take a cue from all the properties and classes you interact with when writing code.  For instance, it is `Form.Height` not `Forms.frmFormHeight`.  Or `TextBox` (singular) vs `TextBoxes` whereas collections *are* plural (`Items`, `Lines` `OpenForms` etc).  And, auto-implemented properties will save you lots of code.  Finally, if you are using classes, Lists and other collections are far better than arrays.